# When does weak* convergence characterize weak* closeness

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, probability-theory

Consider a topological vector space $X$. Suppose $S$ is a subset of $X$. Under what condition, the following implication is true?

"If $\{s_n\}\subset S$ converges to $s\in X$, then $s\in S$. " $\Rightarrow$ "$S$ is closed."

I cannot find a rigorous reference for this.

In particular, consider the space of finite signed measure $\mathscr{M}(\Omega)$ equipped with weak* topology, where $\Omega$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $S\subset\mathscr{P}(\Omega)$ is a subset of probability measures. Suppose for every sequence $\{s_n\}\subset S$ that converges to some $s$, we have $s\in S$. Can we conclude $S$ is weak* closed?

Thank you!

Comment: If your space is first countable, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part of the question has little to do with vector spaces:

> A subset $A$ of a complete metric space $(X,d)$ is closed if and only if it is complete.

This is a standard exercise (solution in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227042/closed-subset-of-complete-metric-space-dont-understand-last-part-of-theorem)).
On (non-metrizable) topological spaces, say that $A$ is *sequentially closed* if it contains the limits of all its **sequences**.

> Sequentially closed sets need not be closed

(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2940442/why-closed-implies-sequentially-closed-but-not-the-converse) for a standard counterexample)

Additionally,

> The *sequential closure* of $A$, i.e. the set of all limit points of sequences *in $A$*, need *not* be sequentially closed

(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458364/why-is-the-sequential-closure-not-sequentially-closed?rq=1)).

Assuming that $X$ is additionally a topological vector space is not of any help:

> there exist weakly sequentially closed subsets of a ($\infty$-dim) Hilbert space that are not weakly closed.

(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2862610/does-weakly-sequentially-closed-imply-weakly-closed)).

Concerning the second part of the question, the answer is **yes**: we can conclude that $S$ is closed since $\mathscr P(\Omega)$ is metrizable.
This is a very particular case of the following fact. A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is *Polish* if there exists a distance $d$ metrizing $\tau$ and additionally such that $(X,d)$ is complete and separable. Endow $\mathscr P(X)$ with the weak topology (induced by the duality with the space $\mathcal C_b(X)$ of continuous bounded functions on $X$). Then

> $(X,\tau)$ is Polish if and only if $\mathscr P(X)$ is Polish.

(see e.g. [A, Thm. 8.9.4])

In the case of $\Omega$ compact in $\mathbb R^n$, the weak topology on $\mathscr P(\Omega)$ coincides with the weak* topology since $\mathcal C_b(\Omega)=\mathcal C_c(\Omega)=\mathcal C(\Omega)$. As a consequence, since $\Omega$ is compact (hence complete and separable, thus Polish), $\mathscr{P}(\Omega)$ is Polish (in particular metrizable), and therefore the conclusion follows from the first part of the answer.

*Trivia:* if Analyst Alice writes "$\mathbb P(\Omega)$" Probabilist Peggy will read "1".

[A] Bogachev, V.I., *Measure Theory*, vol. II

Comment: In [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj48My3l6zxAhUxMuwKHVdZDgsQFjACegQIAhAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprojecteuclid.org%2Fjournals%2Fbulletin-of-the-belgian-mathematical-society-simon-stevin%2Fvolume-16%2Fissue-2%2FA-topological-vector-space-is-Fr%25C3%25A9chet-Urysohn-if-and-only%2F10.36045%2Fbbms%2F1244038142.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2UJRAx6u82d2dNJaJ4DTAu) and references you can see that $C_p([0,1])$ (the continuous real functions on $[0,1]$ in the pointwise topology) is not a sequential space.  It already is a concrete counterexample too for the TVS case.

Comment: $C_p(X)$ spaces are very closely related to weak-* topologies.